# Simplifying the Kahler form

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-forms, complex-geometry

In the link [here](http://www.ulb.ac.be/sciences/ptm/pmif/Rencontres/specgeom.pdf), p.4, it says that, given a fundamental 2-from $\mathcal{K}$
$$\mathcal{K}=\frac{\sqrt{-1}}{2\pi}g_{i\bar{j}}dz^i\wedge d\bar{z}^{\bar{j}},$$
a manifold is said to be Kahler if this form is closed, i.e.,
$$d\mathcal{K} = \frac{\sqrt{-1}}{2\pi} \left( \partial_ig_{j\bar{k}}dz^i\wedge dz^j \wedge d\bar{z}^{\bar{k}}+\partial_{\bar{i}}g_{j\bar{k}}dz^{\bar{i}}\wedge dz^j\wedge d\bar{z}^{\bar{k}}\right)=0.$$
Then this means that both terms are set equal to zero separately, i.e.,
$$\partial_ig_{j\bar{k}}=0 \hspace{1cm} \partial_{\bar{i}}g_{j\bar{k}}=0$$
The author then wrote the following which I didn't understand, he said that what preceded implies
$$\partial_ig_{j\bar{k}}=\partial_jg_{i\bar{k}} \hspace{1cm} \text{and} \hspace{1cm} \partial_{\bar{i}}g_{j\bar{k}}=\partial_{\bar{k}}g_{j\bar{i}}.$$
My question is how did he conclude these last equations from what preceded?

Answer (score 3):

Note that the two form is really 
$$\mathcal{K}=\frac{\sqrt{-1}}{2\pi} \sum_{j,k=1}^n g_{j\bar{k}}dz^j\wedge d\bar{z}^{\bar{k}},$$
so 
$$d\mathcal{K}=\frac{\sqrt{-1}}{2\pi} \left(\sum_{i,j,k=1}^n\partial_i g_{j\bar{k}} dz^i \wedge dz^j\wedge d\bar{z}^{\bar{k}} + \sum_{i,j,k=1}^n\partial_\bar{i} g_{j\bar{k}} d\bar z^\bar{i} \wedge dz^j\wedge d\bar{z}^{\bar{k}}\right).$$
Note that the first term is a $(2, 1)$-form and the second a $(1, 2)$ so both terms has to be zero if $d\mathcal K = 0$. Looking at the $(i, j, \bar k)$ component of the first term, which is 
$$\partial_i g_{j\bar{k}} dz^i \wedge dz^j\wedge d\bar{z}^{\bar{k}} + \partial_j g_{i\bar{k}} dz^j \wedge dz^i\wedge d\bar{z}^{\bar{k}} = \left(\partial_i g_{j\bar{k}} - \partial_j g_{i\bar{k}} \right) dz^i \wedge dz^j\wedge d\bar{z}^{\bar{k}},$$
so we have 
$$\partial_i g_{j\bar{k}} - \partial_j g_{i\bar{k}} = 0,$$
which is your first equation, similarly you get the second equation.

Comment: John, how did you move from the second line to the third one? That is, it seems you switched the indices $i$ and $j$ but not the $k$, isn't it? Why is that? If you can kindly explain?

Comment: That because the $(i, j, \bar k)$ component of the first term is zero. But that component has two inputs, one from $dz^i \wedge dz^j \wedge d\bar z ^\bar{k}$ and the other from $dz^j \wedge dz^i \wedge d\bar z ^\bar{k}$. In dealing with the second one we need to do $dz^i \wedge dz^j = - dz^j \wedge dz^i$, thus the negative sign. @Beyond-formulas

Comment: Yes, but why two inputs and not three or more? Why we dont have a term like $d\bar{z}^{\bar{k}}\wedge dz^i \wedge dz^j$ in addition two the two inputs you presented?

Comment: That's because of the $\bar{}$. $d\bar z ^\bar{k}$ as a basis is different from $dz^i$. @Beyond-formulas

Comment: Are you pointing that if the first term was $\partial_ig_{j\bar{k}}dz^i\wedge dz^j \wedge dz^{\bar{k}}$ instead of $\partial_ig_{j\bar{k}}dz^i\wedge dz^j \wedge d\bar{z}^{\bar{k}}$, then we could have had more input entries?

Comment: @Beyond-formulas Yes if you mean $dz^k$.

Comment: I, also, do not understand what do you precisely mean by inputs here? Is it only exchanging indices of common basis?

Comment: The basis of $(2, 1)$-forms is given by $dz^i \wedge dz^j \wedge d\bar z^{\bar k}$, for $i<j$ and for all $k$. @Beyond-formulas

Comment: Oh, ok. I am not familiar with these forms that is why I got mixed up. I am usually familiar with a single 2-form or a 1-form but never a combination of both. Thanks John!

Comment: Hey John! I was reading your answer and if you do not mind, I have a question on this. In a book I am currently reading, it says that if what you proved in your answer holds (i.e. $\partial_ig_{i\bar{k}}-\partial_jg_{i\bar{k}}=0$) then $g_{i\bar{k}}=\partial_{i}\partial_{\bar{k}}K(z,\bar{z})$ where K is the Kahler potential. My question is how was  $g_{i\bar{k}}=\partial_{i}\partial_{\bar{k}}K(z,\bar{z})$  deduced from what preceded? Thank you.

Comment: \That follows from the fact that $\mathcal K$ is closed and of type $(1,1)$. This is called the $\partial\bar\partial$-lemma and the proof can be found in (e.g.) p.14 of [this note](http://moroianu.perso.math.cnrs.fr/tex/kg.pdf). Note that $\bar\partial $-Poincare lemma is needed. @PhilosophicalPhysics

Comment: Aha.. However, what do you mean by $\bar{\partial}$, I don't have a $\bar{\partial}$ in my $g_{i\bar{k}}=\partial_i\partial_{\bar{k}}K(z, \bar{z})$. Also, if that is the case, then what is$ K(z, \bar{z})$, as the lemma doesn't talk about this. I'm a physicist, that's is why I would appreciate if you could elaborate a bit more, because I'm not familiar with this Lemma. Thanks for your help John.

Comment: @JohnMa I would truly appreciate if you could have a look at the related question here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1577068/the-partial-bar-partial-lemma-dilemma/1577118?noredirect=1#comment3211726_1577118 and hopefully help me figure out where's the problem because you seem to have followed the problem from its very beginning starting from here. If this causes you any inconvenience, please disregard it.